# 'NSInvalidArgumentException' but types of parameter look fine?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm working on refactoring my project a little and I'm making some minor adjustments to the function names. However, after doing this to all relevant classes that have the method to be renamed, I seem to be getting some 'NSInvalidArgumentException' errors where I don't think they should be.

I have this line where my application crashes:

```
[super sceneDidConnectWithOptions:connectionOptions];
```

where the function signature that has this super class invocation is (and reaches this with the debugger telling me connectionOptions is of type UISceneConnectionOptions):

```
- (void)sceneDidConnectWithOptions:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions{
```

where also, the super class's method is defined as:

```
- (void)sceneDidConnectWithOptions:(UISceneConnectionOptions *)connectionOptions;
```

I'm not sure where the NSInvalidArgumentException error would be coming from and don't see any syntax issues as well. I suspected that it could be crashing because of connectionOptions being 'nil', but that's not the case as I put a code block checking for it and it wasn't as well as the debugger showing me that it's not nil.

Comment: Could you share the full error message and the stack trace?

Comment: Got it resolved -- needed to make sure the base class also reflected the function name change. Thanks for offering to help, though!